# Is it possible to use multiple indexes in php?

Tags: php

I would like to do something similar to the following.

```
$ind=array('a','b','c');
$arr['a']=1;
$arr['b']=4;
$arr['c']=7;
$d= $arr[$ind];
print_r($d);
```

It obviously doesnt work and I was wondering if there is still a simple way to do it in 1 or two lines of code.

**EDIT**

Here is a better example to demonstrate what I mean.

```
$ind=array('a','c','b','d','e','a','a');
$arr['a']=1;
$arr['b']=4;
$arr['c']=7;
$d=$arr[$ind];
```

Now I want to receive that $d is equal to 1,7,4,1,1

array_intersect_key doesnt work. Or at least I cant make it work for me. I was thinking array_walk and a lamda function or something. Anyone?

NOTE: This syntax is available in Matlab (well, almost). So you could for example type:

```
arr=rand(20,1);
ind=[1 2 10 2 1 1];
newArr=arr(ind);
```

and it would produce vector of length 6 with the values as indexed by the ind vector.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Arrays can't have arrays as keys, only values.

Comment: I presume you're not talking about creating your own indexes (via `array('a'=>1, 'b'=>4...`) but rather using some form of indirection? (To be honest, I'm not following your example - perhaps you need to update your question to explain a bit more.)

Comment: Do you want composite keys? Or just being able to bulk retrieve values?

Comment: Ive made an edit to better reflect my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the items from `$arr` which have keys matching the values in `$ind`, you can use the following:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 4, 'c' => 7);
$ind = array('a','c');
$d   = array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($ind));
// $d = array('a' => 1, 'c' => 7);
```

The call to `array_flip()` simply "flips" the keys/values in `$ind` (to make it look like `array('a'=>0,'c'=>1)`) then we find the keys intersection with `array_intersect_key()` which returns the items from the first array (`$arr`) which have keys matching the second array (the flipped `$ind`).

---

**Edit** Building on [mario's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523604/is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-indexes-in-php/5523805#5523805) (which is broken at the time of writing, and doesn't do what you appear to want) you could use

```
class MultiIndex extends ArrayObject
{
    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        if (is_array($offset)) {
            $return = array();
            foreach ($offset as $o) {
                if ($this->offsetExists($o)) {
                    $return[] = parent::offsetGet($o);
                }
            }
            return $return;
        } else {
            return parent::offsetGet($offset);
        }
    }
}

$arr = new MultiIndex($arr);
$d = $arr[$ind];
// $d = array(1,7,4,1,1);
```

Comment: That almost worked and then not quite. Ive edited the question to make my intention clearer.

Comment: Thanks. That works fine. I definitely tried to ask the right question and in fact im still surprized there isnt a simpler answer. Anyway, thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Stealing back from salathe, I've compacted the method to the actually required calls, the `$this[$i]` is handled implicitly for existing array keys already. Removed the key capture again.

---

You can embed the utility code to accomplish this, if you use an array object as workaround:

```
class MultiIndex extends ArrayObject {

    function offsetGet ($keys) {

            foreach ($keys as $i) {
                isset($this[$i]) and
                    $r[] = ArrayObject::offsetGet($i);
            }
            return $r;

    }
}
```

Then transform your array into an object to use the multi-index method:

```
$arr = new MultiIndex($arr);
$d = $arr[$ind];
```

This $arr object can still be used with normal assignment or single key queries.

Comment: salathe's answer is correct and produces :Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 7 [2] => 4 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 ). Your new answer produces Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 7 [2] => 4 [3] => [4] => [5] => 1 [6] => 1 )

Comment: Ah I see, undefined keys. Very well, added the short isset() in case anybody stumbles over that.